# Symbolic Computations with Block Matrices in Maple

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic-computation, maple

Due to the derivation of an algorithm I tried to use Maple (9.5) to calculate some block matrix expression. Unfortunately Maple seems to ignore the assumption I set on the variable. Lets consider the following minimal example:

```
restart; with(LinearAlgebra);
assume(A,'SquareMatrix'); 
assume(B,'SquareMatrix'); 
E:=Matrix([A, B]);
```

which results in

$E:=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \end{pmatrix}$

If I now try to evaluate

```
Transpose(E).E
```

I end up with

$E:=\begin{pmatrix} A^2 & AB\\AB & B^2 \end{pmatrix}$

instead of

$E:=\begin{pmatrix} A^TA & A^TB\\B^TA & B^TB \end{pmatrix}$

My question is now why does Maple ignore the assumption set to the variables A and B?

Comment: Also, have you tried `assume(A,'Nonsymmetric')`?

Comment: The assume(E... was a type here, but not in my Maple worksheet. Assuming that A is non symmetric results in "Error, (in ConvertProperty) Nonsymmetric is an invalid property"

Comment: Sorry, I misread the documentation -- it's supposed to be `assume(A,'Non(symmetric)')`, see http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=property

Comment: Even setting it to Non(symmetric) does not change the above described behavior.

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug or peculiarity in Maple, and you it would be better to ask the experts on http://www.mapleprimes.com.

Answer (score 2):

This is not precisely an answer to your question, but too long for a comment: In SymPy (called via `isympy` to set up the symbols), this works as intended:

```
A = MatrixSymbol('A',n,n)
B = MatrixSymbol('B',n,n)
E = BlockMatrix([[A,B]])
block_collapse(E.T*E)
```

results in the desired output

```
⎡ T     T  ⎤
⎢A ⋅A  A ⋅B⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢ T     T  ⎥
⎣B ⋅A  B ⋅B⎦
```

But if I do

```
E = Matrix([[A,B]])
E.T*E
```

I get

```
⎡A⋅A  A⋅B⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎣B⋅A  B⋅B⎦
```

similar to your output (at least SymPy respects that matrix multiplication is non-commutative). This suggests that you should explicitly declare your `E` as a *block* matrix, but I don't know if this is possible with Maple's `LinearAlgebra` (it was with the deprecated `linalg` package).

My recommendation is to ask your question on Maple's Q&A, http://www.mapleprimes.com/ (it's technically off topic on this site, since it about a bug or problem with a specific software package).

---

(If this makes you want to switch to SymPy, [this page](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/SymPy-vs.-Maple) may be helpful.)